# C++ .NET convert System::String to std::string

Tags: .net, c++, string, marshalling

How do you convert System::String to std::string in C++ .NET?

Comment: Don't. Convert to std::wstring. System.String is Unicode, not ASCII

Comment: @MSalters Huh?  You seem to be under the impression that conversion doesn't include translation or that everyone can always choose what API's they're going to interact with...

Comment: Or that `std::string` _must_ be ASCII (hint: it _should_ be UTF-8!)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

There is cleaner syntax if you're using a recent version of .net

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>

#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>

using namespace System;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    System::String^ managedString = "test";

    msclr::interop::marshal_context context;
    std::string standardString = context.marshal_as<std::string>(managedString);

    return 0;
}
```

This also gives you better clean-up in the face of exceptions.

There is an [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384865.aspx) for various other conversions

Comment: Does this also take care of encoding from UTF-16 (.Net default) to UTF-8 (std::string)?

Comment: @zak, internally the code in `msclr::interop::marshal_context` uses the Win32 API `WideCharToMultiByte` which ultimately converts to Windows-1252 encoding, at least in my experience. There may be ways around it, I am not sure, but I think you'll need to do it yourself if you want UTF-8.

For example, the British Pound sign, '£', is converted to the single-byte 0xA3, while the Latin Letter Q, 'ʠ', is converted to a single '?'.

It behaves this way regardless of the Character Set project setting of the C++/CLI project (MBCS or Unicode).

Comment: Since when do we use backslashes (\\) inside #include tags?

Answer (score 29):

And in response to the "easier way" in later versions of C++/CLI, you can do it without the marshal_context.  I know this works in Visual Studio 2010; not sure about prior to that.

---

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>

#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>

using namespace msclr::interop;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    System::String^ managedString = "test";

    std::string standardString = marshal_as<std::string>(managedString);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Comment: Look at the MSDN article Collin linked to to see when to use marshal_as and when to use the marshal_context. Generally speaking the marshal_context is needed when unmanaged resources need to cleaned up.

Comment: The article says one only needs a context if the native type does not have a destructor to do its own cleanup. So, in the case of `std::string`, is this needed?

Comment: The context is not needed for `std::string`. Context is only needed when marshaling from a wrapped type to an unwrapped type (i.e. raw pointer). As listed in [Overview of Marshaling in C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384865.aspx), there are only three instances where the context is needed.

Comment: thanks for this @Mike Johnson,... i was about to leave C++ before this. And now continue again... hehe :D

Comment: I tried to use this, and ran into the issue where it wouldn't work because my System::String^ was a class variable. So I had to copy construct a new String^ and pass that to marshal_as.  I hate Visual Studio.

Comment: The Problem is not Visual Studio, it is .NET.

Answer (score 7):

C# uses the UTF16 format for its strings.
So, besides just converting the types, you should also be conscious about the string's actual format.

When compiling for **Multi-byte Character set** Visual Studio and the Win API assumes UTF8 (Actually windows encoding which is [Windows-28591](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) ).
When compiling for **Unicode Character set** Visual studio and the Win API assume UTF16.

So, you must convert the string from UTF16 to UTF8 format as well, and not just convert to std::string.
This will become necessary when working with multi-character formats like some non-latin languages.

The idea is to decide that `std::wstring` **always** represents **UTF16**.
And `std::string` **always** represents **UTF8**.

This isn't enforced by the compiler, it's more of a good policy to have.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>

#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>

using namespace System;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    System::String^ managedString = "test";

    msclr::interop::marshal_context context;

    //Actual format is UTF16, so represent as wstring
    std::wstring utf16NativeString = context.marshal_as<std::wstring>(managedString); 

    //C++11 format converter
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> convert;

    //convert to UTF8 and std::string
    std::string utf8NativeString = convert.to_bytes(utf16NativeString);

    return 0;
}
```

Or have it in a more compact syntax:

```
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    System::String^ managedString = "test";

    msclr::interop::marshal_context context;
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> convert;

    std::string utf8NativeString = convert.to_bytes(context.marshal_as<std::wstring>(managedString));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _Win API assumes UTF8 (Actually windows encoding which is Windows-28591 )_ -> afaik narrow string API versions assume the system code page, which can be many things but never UTF-8.

Answer (score 6):

```
stdString = toss(systemString);

  static std::string toss( System::String ^ s )
  {
    // convert .NET System::String to std::string
    const char* cstr = (const char*) (Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(s)).ToPointer();
    std::string sstr = cstr;
    Marshal::FreeHGlobal(System::IntPtr((void*)cstr));
    return sstr;
  }
```

Comment: This is the older syntax. I prefer the one that Colin suggested above.

Comment: What if sstr() throws?  Wouldn't that cause cstr to become a leak?

Answer (score 4):

I had too many ambiguous errors showing up with the above answers  ( yes, i'm a C++ noob)

This worked for me for sending string from C# to C++ CLI

C#

```
bool result;
result = mps.Import(mpsToolName);
```

---

C++ CLI

function:

```
bool ManagedMPS::Import(System::String^ mpsToolNameTest)
std::string mpsToolName;
mpsToolName = toStandardString(mpsToolNameTest);
```

function that works from converting String^ to std::string

```
static std::string toStandardString(System::String^ string)
{
 using System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal;
 System::IntPtr pointer = Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(string);
 char* charPointer = reinterpret_cast<char*>(pointer.ToPointer());
 std::string returnString(charPointer, string->Length);
 Marshal::FreeHGlobal(pointer);
 return returnString;
}
```

ON FURTHER RESEARCH, it appears that this is cleaner and safer.

I switched to using this method instead.

```
std::string Utils::ToUnmanagedString(String^ stringIncoming)
{
   std::string unmanagedString = marshal_as<std::string>(stringIncoming);
   return unmanagedString;
}
```

Comment: So how did you manage to get rid of all the IServiceProvider ambiguity errors?

Comment: I don't recall getting those errors.  I was new to C++ , now I'm on another contract/project with different company....   sorry  best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a Windows Runtime Component you can use:

```
String^ systemString = "Hello";
std::wstring ws1(systemString ->Data());
std::string standardString(ws1.begin(), ws1.end());
```

Comment: C++/CLI strings don't seem to have the `Data()` method.