# Converting between managed and unmanaged code

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

I was wondering if the following is valid for converting between a managed string and a standard string:

```
String ^ mymgdstring;
std::string mystdstring = *[PTR TO MYMGDSTRING, NOT SURE OF SYNTAX]
```

(i.e. create a std string which is equal to the dereferenced pointer to a managed string)

If this isn't valid, why not? What is the best method (i.e. most efficient) for converting between these?
Also, how do you get a pointer to a managed string?

Comment: duplicates [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300718/c-net-convert-systemstring-to-stdstring)

Comment: @Eugene - I am aware that similar questions are asked all over the place and a quick Google search yields results but my question is specifically wondering about whether the method I showed is valid and what the most _efficient_ method is for doing the conversion (there seem to be a number of methods out there) because the application I'm writing amy be doing this conversion a lot

Comment: "equal" is going to be difficult, stuffing a utf-16 encoded Unicode string peg into a 8-bit std::string hole requires a big hammer.  Your question is unanswerable unless you specify what kind of lossage you are willing to put up with.

Answer (score 1):

A copy is necessary, because the .NET String data can be moved around during garbage collection.

You can assume `marshal_as` is the most efficient way to do this conversion.  If a faster way is found, `marshal_as` will be updated to use it (it's a template and can be specialized).

You can get an interior pointer to the data of a `System::String` (it will be in Unicode, that's the internal format of .NET strings) using [`PtrToStringChars`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/585whdf9.aspx).  To use it with native code, you must first *pin* the string by using `pin_ptr` instead of `interior_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

C++/CLI comes with a function called MarshalAs which can perform the conversion.