# C# String vs std:string: Issue in passing strings

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, opencv, image-processing, c++-cli

Please have a look at the following `opencv` code

```
void ImageWriter::writeImage(Mat image)
{
    number++;
    String name="D:/OpenCV Final Year/Images/intruder";
    name+=number;
    name+=".bmp";

    //imwrite("D:/OpenCV Final Year/Images/intruder.bmp",image);
    imwrite(name,image);
}
```

Here, all I can say is that `imwrite()` is not writing anything! There is no errors but no outputs as well. If I use the commented version of the `imwrite()` it works as expected . But I can't use it because I need to write number of images, so the name change done by `number` integer variable is important.  I believe the issue is with the `name` string.

However this `name` is in type of `C#` and that is because `std:string` conflicted.

How can I make this dynamic name creation success and make the get the `imwrite()` to work?

Comment: What do you mean "`std::string` conflicted"? [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1300718/1601291) addresses conversion between the two types.

Comment: @Aurelius: Pardon me for the delay of my reply. For std:string, it generate errors

Comment: What kind of errors? Compile errors? Runtime errors? What do they say?

Comment: @Aurelius: Sorry for the delay again. The error is "error: c2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from System::String ^ to std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> "

Answer (score 1):

Just thoughts
Have you tried:

1. Use char array? (`char[]`)
2. `StringStream`
3. String Format instead of `+=`

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you are attempting to pass a managed .NET System::String object to a function that is expecting an std::string.  Looking at the documentation here [(OpenCV Documents C++ imwrite)](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imwrite#bool%20imwrite%28const%20string&%20filename,%20InputArray%20img,%20const%20vector%3Cint%3E&%20params%29) it would appear that it is expecting a const string& type.

If you are writing this in C# there isn't a way of being able to 'declare' an std::string object.

I would start by seeing if name.ToCharArray() would work.  Although this will produce a managed array it is possible the compiler may work out the required conversion from managed char array to native.

As you are using C++/CLI you need to marshal your managed string to the std format:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
using namespace System;

void MarshalString (String^ s, string& os )
{
   using namespace Runtime::InteropServices;
   const char* chars = 
      (const char*)(Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(s)).ToPointer();
   os = chars;
   Marshal::FreeHGlobal(IntPtr((void*)chars));
}

void ImageWriter::writeImage(Mat image)
{
    number++;
    String name="D:/OpenCV Final Year/Images/intruder";
    name+=number;
    name+=".bmp";

    string nativeString;
    MarshalString(name, nativeString);

    imwrite(nativeString, image);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am writing in C++/CLI\