# How to convert C++/CLI string to const char*

Tags: c#, c++, c, dll

I've got a C++/CLI DLL I plan to use as an adapter between my C# DLL and native C++ clients. I need to pass strings in both directions. The adapter is compiled with VS2013 but needs to support clients built with VS2008 so I'm using const char* in the API. But what I've got isn't working even when both are VS2013-built.

Elsewhere, I found advice to use msclr\marshal.h, so I created:

```
using namespace msclr::interop;
System::String^ ToCliString(const char* s)
{
    System::String ^result = marshal_as<System::String^>(s);
    return result;
}    
const char* ToCppString(System::String^ s)
{
    msclr::interop::marshal_context context;
    const char* result = context.marshal_as<const char*>(s);
    return result;
}
```

To test these, I created a round-trip conversion method in my C++/CLI DLL:

```
const char* Foo(const char *cstar)
{
    System::String^ cli = ::ToCliString(cstar);

    if (cli == "abc")
    {
        MessageBox::Show("const char* -> CLI: OK");
    }

    const char* cstar2 = ::ToCppString(cli);

    if (std::strcmp(cstar2, "abc") == 0)
    {
        MessageBox::Show("CLI -> const char*: OK");
    }
    else if (std::strcmp(cstar2, "") == 0)
    {
        MessageBox::Show("ToCppString returned empty string");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox::Show("ToCppString returned something else");
    }

    return cstar2;
}
```

When the native C++ client calls Foo("abc"), the 1st message gets displayed, the "returned something else" message gets displayed and the client receives junk (îþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþÞ›vÚ§). So it would seem my 2nd conversion is not working.

***UPDATE***

Here's the final solution I used.

I used zneaks' advice to marshall to std::string and PaulMcKenzie's advice to pass a caller-allocated char* instead of returning const char*. Thank you both.

```
void ToCppString(System::String^ input, char* output)
{
    std::string temp= marshal_as<std::string>(input);
    strcpy(output, temp.c_str());
}

void Foo(const char* input, char* output)
{
    System::String^ cli = ::ToCliString(input);
    ::ToCppString(cli, output);
}
```

Comment: You're returning a pointer to a local variable `cstar2`, which is undefined behavior.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie So to pass a string from C# to the native C++ client, the client needs to pass a char * that the adapter "fills"?

Comment: That is the usual way it's done.  The client provides the buffer and the C++ code fills the buffer with the data.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Does the client need to call delete to prevent a memory leak then? I guess they can allocate buffer once, call many functions in my API,and delete when they're finished. So my API should include another parm so they can tell me the max size message I can return? Or more appropriate to have a property client can query to determine my max message length?

Comment: The client is responsible for maintaining the buffer correctly.  It may have been allocated with `new[] /  delete[]`, it could even be a `std::vector<char>` and you're passing `std::vector<char>::data()`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `marshal_context` owns the char pointer that you got, so it is [deallocated when your function returns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-ca/library/bb384856.aspx):

> This example creates a context for marshaling from a **System::String** to a **const char *** variable type.The converted data will not be valid after the line that deletes the context.

Consider using [`marshal_as<std::string>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1300903) instead, since the string is allowed to outlive the `marshal_context`.

Comment: I just tried replacing the last 2 lines of ToCppString with std::string result = context.marshal_as<std::string>(s); return result.c_str();  But same result. I wonder, since the local std::string goes out of scope, will the value returned by its c_str() function still be valid?

Comment: Got it, now using strcpy into a new parameter. Will post my solution shortly.

Comment: @JimC, yes, the pointer returned by `c_str()` is owned by the string and deallocated when the function returns, so you were essentially back with the same problem. You can return a `std::string`, though.

Comment: I could but it would be just kicking the can because I can't return the std::string all the way to the app (I have to support apps built with a different version of Visual Studio.)

Comment: Careful to delete the strings yourself then.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, please be aware that VC++ 2008 express does not contains marshal header files (marshal.h and others), so you have to use VC++ 2008 pro or onwards. Looks like those header files are included in express edition since VS2010.