# convert a combobox value to std::string

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, visual-c++

I want to recuperate a combobox value as an `std::string` to use it  as a parameter in another function.

```
std::string mystring = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(myComboBox->Text->ToString());
```

but it didn't work. Can someone help me.

Comment: you should probably share the error message with us

Comment: The error is that i can't use the combobox value as a paramaeter in my 'function(std::string variable1)'. i need to convert it to std::string first.

Comment: The error i get : 'no suitable constructor exists to convert from "System::String ^" to "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>" ' which is not surprising.

Comment: so, your real question is how to converst System::String^ to std::string? Isn't it. This link may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300718/c-net-convert-systemstring-to-stdstring

Comment: I am having the error :' Error C4996 'msclr::interop::error_reporting_helper<_To_Type,_From_Type,false>::marshal_as': This conversion is not supported by the library or the header file needed for this conversion is not included.  Please refer to the documentation on 'How to: Extend the Marshaling Library' for adding your own marshaling method. '

Comment: i found the solution :    IntPtr p = Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(dev);
   string DeviceName;
   DeviceName = static_cast<char*>(p.ToPointer());
   Marshal::FreeHGlobal(p);