# Convert System::String^ to cv::String

Tags: string, opencv, pointers, visual-c++

I searched for a while trying to find if there was a similar question, but couldn't.

How can I convert `System::String^` (from VC++) to `cv::String` (from OpenCV)?

```
double x, y;
x = 10;
y = 10;
System::String ^ displayString = System::String::Concat("( ", x, " , ", y, " )");
char * test1 = displayString->ToCharArray;
cv::String test = cv::String(test1)
```

gives the error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C3867   'System::String::ToCharArray': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member   RobocopComputerVision   RobocopComputerVision   .cpp    156
```

What is the best way to convert `System::String^` to `cv::String`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300718/c-net-convert-systemstring-to-stdstring#1300903

Comment: @zindarod That worked because cv::String had a constructor for std::String. Do you want to write it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Just try this,

```
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>
using namespace msclr::interop;
/* ... ... */
System::String ^ displayString = System::String::Concat("( ", x, " , ", y,")");
cv::String test = marshal_as<std::string>(displayString);
```