# CPP issue in wstring to str conversion

Tags: c++, unicode

I'm trying to convert wstring to string and tried the below code:

```
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf16<wchar_t>, wchar_t> utf8convertor;
std::string str = utf8convertor.to_bytes(utf16str);
```

My input is "Doc 01". But I get the output as " D o c   0 1".

Any help on what I'm doing wrongly

Comment: Shouldn't that be `std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>`?

Comment: Yes. This is the correct one to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34461757/249816) helped me.

And here's the code I arrived at:

```
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> convert;
std::string str = convert.to_bytes(utf16str);
```