# C# 'String' to C++ 'std::string'

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

I have a C# DLL, having below function:

```
[DllExport(ExportName = "getOutputString", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static String getOutputString()
{
    String managedString = "123456789012345678901234567890";
    return managedString;
}
```

and a C++ application to use the above function as:

```
HMODULE mod = LoadLibraryA("MyCustomDLL.dll");
using GetOutputString = std::string (__stdcall *) ();
GetOutputString getOutputString = reinterpret_cast<GetOutputString>(GetProcAddress(mod, "getOutputString"));
```

and want to store the string from DLL in C++ variable as:

```
std::string myVariable = getOutputString();
```

When I run the C++ application, it crashes.

But when i just use the function in std::printf code works perfectly:

```
std::printf("String from DLL: %s\n", getOutputString());
```

My actual task is to get an Array of String from DLL, but if you can help me getting a simple String from C# to std::string in C++, that would be great.

Or just give me a hint to save printed string via std::printf( ) in a variable of type std::string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-for-strings#strings-used-in-platform-invoke), C# marshals `string` objects as simple "pointer to a null-terminated array of ANSI characters", or `const char *` in C++ terms.

If you change the typedef of `GetOutputString` to return a `const char *`, everything will work.

Comment: great, it worked. Also i tried without 'const' only char* works too. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I suggest explicitly specifying `UnmanagedType.LPUTF8Str` or `UnmanagedType.LPWStr` to support Unicode, or `UnmanagedType.BStr`

Answer (score 1):

C++ with CLI, use System::String^ (this is a .Net string, i.e. same as C#'s)

```
using GetOutputString = System::String^ (__stdcall *) ();
```

Then you can do this

```
std::string standardString = context.marshal_as<std::string>(managedString);
```

(Credit [https://stackoverflow.com/a/1300903/1848953])